# How to set constant globally in python Django project

Tags: python, django, constants

I am making web application where I want to set some **constant's** globally so I can access it in multiple apps present in my Django project.

Comment: The constants can be in the settings.py or  you could put them anywhere and import them from that place into your view/model/module code.

Answer (score 5):

Define the constant in your [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/) file

```
MY_CONSTANT = 123
```

Then use it in the following way:

```
from django.conf import settings

print(settings.MY_CONSTANT)
```